# New Linux Mint Update Won't Let my Computer Boot

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, crash

last night I installed the updates for Linux Mint 17.1 from the updates manager.  I hadn't installed them for a couple weeks but I was about to do something on the internet where I wanted to make sure I had the latest security updates. It told me it would install a new Nvidia driver (I think it was something like 367) as well as a couple other packages. I clicked okay, and then it downloaded and installed for about three minutes. When it was done, it said it was unable to update Firefox (this is a problem I have never had before).  I closed it and my computer continued to work just fine.

However, when I tried to boot my computer this morning, it said it was missing a chipset and then just had a spinning loading cursor forever.  I tried rebooting and it did the same thing.

Any idea on how to recover from this? I have a massive project I'm working on that I don't want to loose all my data from (although I do have a backup from about a week ago...)

Comment: use a bootable usb stick to boot up and from there you can get your projects... in a good condition..

Comment: @SanjeevPrasadThakur Can you explain how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: do you have a live bootable usb ???

Comment: @SanjeevPrasadThakur No, but I can make one. Does it need to be the same operating system?

Comment: oh not at all it may NOT be the same os... but should have a linux operating system.. (may be options are available in OS other than linux os but i don't know about that other options...). you have to make a bootable usb stick... with live options...

Comment: @SanjeevPrasadThakur What are live options? Also, will this method allow me to restore my original hard drive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49536/discussion-between-sanjeev-prasad-thakur-and-anson-savage).

Answer (score 1):

Boot your system , from GRUB menu choose "Advanced option for linux mint" , then choose a working kernel version (do not choose the first one)

**edit**

From the terminal list the latest changes through `cat /var/log/apt/history.log` you will get something like:

```
Start-Date: 2016-12-03  .....
Commandline: e,g:  /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade , apt install somepackages ,/usr/sbin/synaptic ,
Requested-By: user...
Install: ...
End-Date ....
```

Verify the list of the latest upgraded package, first uninstall the new installed Nvidia driver then reboot , if doesn't work maybe you need to uninstall some other packages (e,g: a backported package)

Comment: Okay, I got into GRUB, but there are no advanced options...

Comment: Okay, sweet! I'm trying it out now.

Comment: Okay, so I've got to the log, which looks great, but is there anyway to revert a package rather than uninstall it?

Comment: @AnsonSavage First uninstall the nvidia driver , after rebooting successfully ,reinstall the driver, Check for update , Verify the list of package from the update manager , if there an update for the driver un-check it maybe the problem the problem come from the level 3 , 4 or 5

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help!

I fixed it using this tutorial: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=122257

Answer (score 0):

use a bootable usb stick to boot up and from there you can get your projects... in a good condition..