# How to revert recently upgraded packages

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, nvidia

I just did an update from the Linux Mint package manager. I restarted my computer and the update messed tons of stuff up. (I think the main problem is the Nvidia driver that was updated... Even though I switched back to the Nouveau driver in the Driver Manager, the update is still messing things up).

Symptoms: Running in software rendering mode, really slow screen refreshing, dumbed down NVIDIA X Server app, no GPU rendering in Blender, second monitor not getting any signal, etc.

Anyhow, I pulled up the Synaptic Package Manager and looked at the update History and saw the following:

[image]

I'm assuming I can just sudo apt-get remove all the packages that were newly installed, but how can I revert the Nvidia packages that were upgraded to their previous version?

Thanks in advance!

(Something terrible happens every time Nvidia tries to update. [Last time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327817/new-linux-mint-update-wont-let-my-computer-boot) it wouldn't let my computer even boot. I think I've learned my lesson now, ha ha.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it doesn't help that some guy downvoted my answer (good heck guys, that makes it a lot less likely for people to want to help; it makes people not even read the question in the first place).

Anyhow, I marked libcuda1-384 and nvidia-384 for complete removal, and rebooted my computer. This didn't work, so I tried switching to the Nvidia-384 proprietary driver and rebooted. Everything appears to be back to normal.

This is puzzling for a number of reasons.

1. My driver manager showed that I was using the Nouveau driver before, which worked perfectly. Using the nvidia-384 would mess things up.
2. For some reason, removing those packages either allowed nvidia-384 to work, or maybe I was using nvidia-3894 all along and my driver manager was giving me the wrong information.

So I fixed the problem, but I didn't learn why it happened or how to fix it. What the heck?